# Unable to install SSIS on SQL Server 2016 due to SQL Server 2012 Native client error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-native-client

I am trying to add SSIS to SQL Server 2016, but I keep getting the error message: 
"An installation package for the product Microsoft SQL SERVER 2012 Native Client cannot be found. Try the installation again using a valid copy of the installation package 'slincli.msi'".

I downloaded slincli.msi file from Microsoft website and tried to install it but this time I got this error message:
"Installation of SQL Server 2012 Native Client failed because a higher version already exists on the machine. To proceed, uninstall the higher version and then run SQL Server 2012 Native Client Setup again."

I cannot uninstall Native Client because I don't want to make trouble with the SQL server 2016 database that already has been installed and is working.

I also tried to install SQL Server 2016 SP2 but it didn't install Native Client too.

I am so desperate now as I have spent more than a day to resolve this problem.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally uninstalled the Native client and installed SSIS. Fortunately, it didn't break anything and the database is up and running.